# Saving the checked button state when back button pressed or app exited with SharedPreferences and onCheckChangeListener

Tags: java, android, android-listview, fragment, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make an android app that allows users to block apps for a specific period of time. So I have a listview of installed apps in a fragment with a switch button next to it.

I want it to stay checked when the user checks its or unchecks it after they press back and exit the app.

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using setOnCheckedChangeListener and Shared Preferences; however; I am having trouble saving the button state in my BaseAdapter class.

```
    holder.ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                //itemChecked[position] = true;
                b = true;
                holder.ck1.setChecked(b);
                Log.i("This is", " checked: " + position);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("checkBox1", b);
                editor.commit();

            } else {
                //itemChecked[position] = false;
                b= false;
                holder.ck1.setChecked(b);
                Log.i("This is", " not checked: " + position);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("checkBox1", b);
                editor.commit();

            }
        }

    });
    sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkBox1",false));

    // I think that maybe instead of false I should put the boolean b I defined in the method but I am not sure how to get it .


    return convertView;

}
```

How I do I modify this to reach to desired result?

Comment: isnt ur vlaues getting saved?

Comment: No because we I go back and forth the buttons changed back to off

Comment: you wont be able to what you want with how you are doing it now. You are currently overriding the same preference every time you change the state of a button. you need to create a separate preference for each list item but at that point you might as well keep a database of the values

Comment: Wait so there is no way to do it without doing it that way? Because obviously creating a separate preference is not optimal

Comment: no you keep overwriting the same preference every time you make a change, you need to save each one individually somewhere

Comment: Oh okay. I see. Then in that case, I guess my real question is how should I go about doing that

Comment: create a database and save them there

Comment: I should probably look deeply into this then right? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: yes that would be a start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58517/discussion-between-xijiaopin-and-tyczj).

Answer (score 0):

I think whenever the activity created it automatically calls onCheckedChange and your SharedPreferences overwrite by default values. so I think you can use onStop to update the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) 
        { 
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean(pakagename, b);
                editor.commit();
        }

});

sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(pakagename,false));
return convertView;

}
```

pakagename holds the package name of that particular listitem. Otherwise if you are targeting above api level 11, you can use a set in sharedpreferences to store all the checked package names. This is the easy way. Otherwise you can save the list of checked applications in a database.

Comment: I'm not sure why it still is not saving the checked boxes after I go back'

Comment: You were saving your preference in one sharedpreferences, and trying to fetch the saved preference from another. Both had to be the same.

Comment: I am not sure if I am placing this code segment in the correct spot.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the requested feature. Check my code:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("conditionCheck", MODE_PRIVATE); 
switchCompat.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("switchCondition",false));        
switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("conditionCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        if (switchCompat.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked Condition True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editor.putBoolean("switchCondition",switchCompat.isChecked());
            editor.commit();    
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked Condition False", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editor.putBoolean("switchCondition",switchCompat.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
});
```